# Configuring ExtraTiC Material values

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tinkers-construct

Is there a way to configure the values for the different Tinker's Construct materials added by, say, ExtraTiC? Right now the values I have for the collection of mods I play with feels unbalanced. The only configuration options I could find (in ExtraTiC and IguanaTweaks) allow restricting which parts can be crafted. I want to change the values for the parts instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can if you use Minetweaker + Modtweaker.

Read up on how to use Minetweaker here:
http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/wiki/Main_Page

The modtweaker documentation for Tinker's construct is here:
http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/wiki/ModTweaker:TConstruct_Support

You can download them here if you don't have them yet
http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/downloads.html
http://minecraft.curseforge.com/mc-mods/220954-modtweaker

There is a section in there on setting tool stats. use `/minetweaker materials` to get a list of the materials you have installed and write a script in `minecraft/scripts/TC.zs` to rewrite whatever properties you want.